# convert int to nsumber*

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have

NsNumber *object = nill;

I want to set object = 1

it raise error in conversion

how to convert int to nsnumber  and want to increment the nsnumber by 1

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value
```

For example:

```
NSNumber *object = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Comment: how to increment it after that by 1

Comment: `object = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[object intValue]+1];`

Answer (score 2):

```
int myInt = 10;
NSNumber * myNumber = [ NSNumber numberWithInt: myInt ];
```

See the **NSNumber** documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: just as a note, the returned value is an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set object = 1

```
object = [ NSNumber numberWithInt:1 ] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use NSUInteger instead of an NSNumber:

```
NSUInteger myint = 1;    //declare integer "myint" and set to 1
myint++;                 //increment myint
```

Note that when declaring a NSUInteger, you do not put a * after the type since it is not an object, but rather a typedef that describes a unsigned integer.

As bbum noted below, since NSUInteger is not an object, it cannot be used in places where an object is required (dictionaries, etc.), so this may or may not be a solution to your problem depending on context.

Comment: This'll likely raise more questions than it answers;  NSUinteger is not an object and cannot be used in dictionaries, etc, which was most likely the motivation for the original question.

Comment: Good point. I defaulted to using "object" since that was in the original post, but in hindsight, it's obviously misleading. I'll edit it to change the variable name.